# The meaning of "*this" in C++

Tags: c++, pointers, this

```
vecteur& vecteur::operator+=(const vecteur& autre)
{
    x += autre.x;
    y += autre.y;
    z += autre.z;
    return *this;
}
```

What does `*this` mean in that case?

Is there any possibility to call it differently, like simply `return vecteur`?

Comment: `vecteur` is a type, `*this` is a value

Comment: `vecteur` is a type, so cannot be returned.  (Image if you had 2 `vecteur ` variables; which would such a statement return?)

Comment: [Handy documentation on `this`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/this) because it turns out `this` has subtlety and a few quirks around the edges.

Answer (score 2):

`this` is a pointer to the object that the method is being called on. `*this` is that pointer being dereferenced (i.e. accessing the actual object itself).